# How to use SparkSQL Convert ".txt" to ".parquet" in Spark 2.1.0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Look, I used "spark-shell" command to test it.(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

```
scala> case class IP(country: String) extends Serializable
17/07/05 11:20:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 192.168.50.3:42868 in memory (size: 33.1 KB, free: 93.3 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 192.168.50.3:40888 in memory (size: 33.1 KB, free: 93.3 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 0
17/07/05 11:20:09 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1
defined class IP

scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

scala> val df = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/test/guchao/ip.txt").map(x => x.split("\\|", -1)).map(x => IP(x(0))).toDF()
17/07/05 11:20:36 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 216.5 KB, free 92.9 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:36 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 20.8 KB, free 92.8 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:36 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 192.168.50.3:42868 (size: 20.8 KB, free: 93.3 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:36 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from textFile at :33
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [country: string]

scala> df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("/test/guchao/ip.parquet")
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO ParquetFileFormat: Using default output committer for Parquet: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol: Using user defined output committer class org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol: Using output committer class org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 88.405717 ms
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: save at :36
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (save at :36) with 2 output partitions
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (save at :36)
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[12] at save at :36), which has no missing parents
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 77.3 KB, free 92.8 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 29.3 KB, free 92.7 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on 192.168.50.3:42868 (size: 29.3 KB, free: 93.2 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[12] at save at :36)
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 2 tasks
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, 192.168.50.3, executor 0, partition 0, ANY, 6027 bytes)
17/07/05 11:20:44 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on 192.168.50.3:40888 (size: 29.3 KB, free: 93.3 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:45 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on 192.168.50.3:40888 (size: 20.8 KB, free: 93.2 MB)
17/07/05 11:20:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, 192.168.50.3, executor 0, partition 1, ANY, 6027 bytes)
17/07/05 11:20:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) in 679 ms on 192.168.50.3 (executor 0) (1/2)
17/07/05 11:20:46 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (save at :36) finished in 1.476 s
17/07/05 11:20:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: save at :36, took 1.597097 s
17/07/05 11:20:46 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) in 804 ms on 192.168.50.3 (executor 0) (2/2)
17/07/05 11:20:46 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/07/05 11:20:46 INFO FileFormatWriter: Job null committed.
```

but the result is:

`[root@master ~]# hdfs dfs -ls -h /test/guchao
17/07/05 11:20:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2017-07-05 11:20 /test/guchao/ip.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup     23.9 M 2017-07-05 10:05 /test/guchao/ip.txt`

Why does this size of "ip.parquet" is 0?  I don't understand and confuse.

Thanks!

Comment: You're doing a lot more than just converting text to parquet. You're splitting and mapping. Maybe the Dataframe is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hdfs dfs -ls -h <path>` shows the size of files and shows 0 for the directory.

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save("/test/guchao/ip.parquet")
```

This creates the directory as `/test/guchao/ip.parquet` which has the part files inside this directory, thats why it shows 0 size

```
hadoop fs -ls /test/guchao/ip.parquet
```

this should show you the actual size of output files

If you want to get size of directory than you can use

```
hadoop fs -du -s /test/guchao/ip.parquet
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does happens some time don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

/test/guchao/ip.parquet is a directory, get into the directory and you should find something like part-00000 which will be the file you are looking for.

hadoop fs -ls /test/guchao/ip.parquet